# How can I format this data with bash script

Tags: regex, bash

I want to format data from this

```
header1|header2|header3
"ID001"|"""TEST"""|"
TEST TEST TEST"|"TEST 4"
"ID002"|"TEST"|"TESTTESTTEST"|"TEST 5"
```

into

```
header1|header2|header3
"ID001"|"TEST"|"TEST TEST TEST"|"TEST 4"
"ID002"|"TEST"|"TESTTESTTEST"|"TEST 5"
```

So the logics are

- keep the header as original
- check other lines if not start with " then move this line to end of previous line
- replace """ to "

I want to format this with bash script.

I've created this line but still not working

```
#!/bin/bash


if [ $# -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "No arguments supplied"
exit;
fi

FOLD=$1"*"
CHECK=$1"/bix.done"



if test -f $CHECK; then
date > /result.txt
echo "starting Covert.... "
echo "from folder : " $1    


    for file in $FOLD
    do
          if [[ $file != *History* ]]; then
        if  [[ $file == *.csv ]]; then
            FILETEMP=$file".temp"
            mv $file $FILETEMP
            awk '/^"/ {if (f) print f; f=$0; next} {f=f FS $0} END {print f}' $FILETEMP > $file
            #rm $FILETEMP           
        fi
          fi

    done
date > /home/result.txt

fi



#ls $1 -l
```

Comment: The `awk` program works for me on the example data you gave. However, your variable `file` holds the name of a *folder*, not of a file. Your loop will be executed only once, with `file` set to `$FOLD`. Maybe you want something like `for file in $FOLD/*.csv`.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1b;:a;N;/\n"/!s/\n//;ta;s/"""/"/g;P;D' file
```

Always print the first header line. Append the next line to the current line and if that line does not begin with a `"` remove the newline and repeat until there is such a line. Now substitute a single `"` for `"""` globally, print the first line and repeat.

Comment: thanks for help, It can replace """ to " , but for moving line without " to previous line is not working

Answer (score 0):

Specific to joining the 2nd line and condensing the muliple-double quotes to a single double-quote you could do:

```
sed '2{s/""*/"/g;h;N;s/\n//}' file
```

- print all lines by default, except for
- the `2` second line, then

  - `s/""*/"/g` substitute multiple double quotes for a single double quote,
  - `h` copy pattern-space to hold space,
  - `N` append the next line to hold space, and
  - `s/\n//` substitute the `'\n'` with nothing joining the line.

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in `file` you could do:

```
$ sed '2{s/""*/"/g;h;N;s/\n//}' file
header1|header2|header3
"ID001"|"TEST"|"TEST TEST TEST"|"TEST 4"
"ID002"|"TEST"|"TESTTESTTEST"|"TEST 5"
```

(**note:** if you need to condense multiple double quotes to single double quotes in all lines, you can turn the command around and use `sed 's/""*/"/g;2{h;N;s/\n//}'`)

Answer (score 0):

It's been resolved with below codes

```
if test -f $CHECK; then
date > /home/startconvert.txt
echo "starting Convert.... "
echo "from folder : " $1    


    for file in $FOLD
    do
       if [[ $file != *History* ]]; then
        if  [[ $file == *.csv ]]; then
            #FILETEMP=$file".temp"
            #mv $file $FILETEMP
            #awk '/^"/ {if (f) print f; f=$0; next} {f=f FS $0} END {print f}' $FILETEMP > $file
            #rm $FILETEMP           

             perl -i -0777pe 's/\r\n([^"])/ $1/g' $file;
             perl -i -0777pe 's/\n"""/"/' $file;
             perl -i -0777pe 's/\r("\|)/ $1/g' $file;
             sed -i -e 's/"""/"/g' $file;
             perl -i -0777pe 's/\n([^"])/ $1/g' $file;
             perl -i -0777pe 's/\n("\|)/ $1/g' $file;
             sed -i -e 's/""-/-/g' $file;
             perl -i -0777pe 's/\n([^"])/ $1/g' $file;
             perl -i -0777pe 's/\r([^"])/ $1/g' $file;
             perl -i -0777pe 's/\r\n([^"])/ $1/g' $file;
        fi
       fi

    done
date > /home/endconvert.txt

fi
```

Comment: appreciate if anyone want to improve this code, thank you

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about the bash part, this expression though,

```
[\r\n]^([^"])
```

with a replacement of `$1` might be somewhat close.

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/WTEC6N/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/WTEC6N/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---